# Facebook Fan page like check

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I would like to see of visitor of my website is already fan of my fanpage.

So if somebody visits my website,i would like to ask him to visit my fanpage only, if he is not fan already.I dont want to ask for permission. Just check, if he likes the fanpage or not. 
Is there possibility to do this? I am not experienced in this Facebook API, this is why i ask for an idea for doing this

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. However, I was looking for an app that would, when someone asks a question on SO, check if they've accepted the answers to their previous questions. oh wait, that one _can_ be done. please go back and make sure to accept answers to your previous questions that were helpful/solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) by querying [page_fan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) table, you have to get `user_likes` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) before doing this...

Answer (score 0):

It is now against Facebook's policies to gate an app or content within an app based on if someone has liked your page.

Use of the  `user_likes` permission will not be approved for use by Facebook via Login Review if you're using it for the purpose of like gating.

In addition, FQL is now deprecated and should no longer be used for new apps.

See the announcement here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/