# Facebook FQL on page_fan does not seem to require user_likes permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

The FQL doc on [page_fan](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) does not have any reference to specific permissions required to query this table (unlike other tables which list required permissions at the bottom).

Does that mean that this table can be queried without the 'user_likes' permission which is necessary for [graph.facebook.com/user-id/likes/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/#readmodifiers) end-point ? There are several questions on stackoverflow referring to page_fan (from a year or so ago) that talk about user_likes being necessary to access the page_fan table (e.g. [sample1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771442/facebook-fan-page-like-check/7775428#7775428), [sample2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232657/user-likes-permission-not-required-bug), etc).

I have tested this to work (successfully queried results from page_fan using a token without the user_likes permissions) even after forcing the privacy settings on likes to be strict.

So has this recently changed where Facebook does not require the user_likes for page_fan, or is this is not expected to work consistently without the user_likes ?

Sorry if I am missing something and will appreciate it very much if somebody can share insights (I am pretty sure there are many others who will benefit from this).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I personally cannot retrieve my likes if I haven't given the "user_likes" permission, using an Access Token with default permissions (basic profile and friendlist). I can't imagine that this works. Otherwise, please post you FQL code.